# $.get data object returns undefined or empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the below code the data variable returns a string, that I convert back into an object like so $( data ) but if I do something like this:

```
$(data).find(".className").text(); //or the below
$(data).find(".someClass").html()
```

They either output "" or undefined.

The code is quite simple and looks like this:

```
lurl = "some/url.html"
$.get( lUrl, function( data ) {
     console.log( $(data).find(".someClass").text() );
});
```

some/url.html

```
<div class="someClass">some text</div>
```

as you probably figured out the second code is not the original code since it's a normal webpage and rather large :)

can anyone see a reason why the above shouldn't work? Could it be an encoding problem? The target page isn't UTF8 but an ISO format.

Comment: Can you share what $(data) returns?

Comment: So in short, you are returning an element ID, in which there is .someClass element? And You want to get it's content? Can you log data, then $(data).length ?

Comment: And `url.html` probably contains more HTML than just one element, otherwise why would you be using `find` ?

Comment: the $(data) is returning the intire source of the target page but as a text string

@Beri not exactly but close enough. I am trying to fetch an element, I have done this a gasillion times before and can't for the life of me see what I am doing wrong today :)

Comment: @adeneo yup, as I stated.

Comment: @RenéHaugeReinholdt log please for us $(data).find(".someClass").length and $(data).length, it will show us what element you are missing, or you have more than one found:)

Comment: I ain't missing an element. I have run the find() on the target page and it grabs exactingly what I am aiming for. But one thing I have notised when I log the obejct is that it writes context: undefined... but the shorthand $.get should set the "context" to "document,body"... hmm

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be rather simple.. when I dived down into the code of the target page I discovered that the element that I was targeting was being appended to the page with javascript. So when I called it via $.get the element I was targeting didn't exist.

thx for the rubber ducking everyone.. feel kinda dumb right now :)